# Core Data:Unable to insert Data into the table, ios7

Tags: objective-c, core-data, ios7

I am trying to store location information using Core data

Here is my code

```
-(void)saveCity:(NSDictionary *)dict{
    [self.progressLabel setText:@"Saving current location in the database "];
    NSEntityDescription *entitydesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Location" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSManagedObject *newLocation = [[NSManagedObject alloc]initWithEntity:entitydesc insertIntoManagedObjectContext:context];

    NSLog(@"saving city:%@", dict);
    [newLocation setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"country"] forKey:@"country"];
    [newLocation setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"current"] forKey:@"current"];
    [newLocation setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"name"] forKey:@"name"];
    [newLocation setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"timediff"] forKey:@"timediff"];
    [newLocation setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"latitude"] forKey:@"latitude"];
    [newLocation setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"longitude"] forKey:@"longitude"];

    NSError *error;
    [context save:&error];

}
```

Should work but when I go into my simulator's .sqlite and view it I don't see any data. I can see that the table is there but no data.

I first thought maybe my dictionary is empty so I logged it and it is not.

Comment: Maybe something is going wrong while you're saving the managed object context. Right now, you're supplying an `NSError` to the save method but you're not saving or printing its contents if an error occurs. Add `NSLog(@"Error: %@", error)` below your call to save and check in the console if an error is printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are testing this in iOS 7 then the issue is with journalling on the sqlite file.  SQLite writes were changed in iOS 7 to journal mode so writes are added to secondary files first and then rolled up later.

If, upon subsequent launch, you are seeing your data in your UI then there is nothing to change.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you managedObjectContext in that view controller is being set... Check to make sure it is not nil.